# How to use Hibernate eqOrIsNull()

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two rows in MySQL like this

```
+---------+---------+
| foo     | bar     |
+---------+---------+
|         | NULL    |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

Where empty are empty strings `""`.

Now I want to get both of them. I use `Criteria` and `Restrictions.eqOrIsNull()` on both columns, but it always returns only one row.

The code is like this

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("foo", ""));
        .add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("bar", ""));
```

And when I add criteria only on `foo`, it returns two rows. But for `bar`, it only returns the second, which is empty.

The [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) says, `Apply an "equal" constraint to the named property. If the value is null, instead apply "is null".` So am I getting this wrong, or it should be used in other ways?

**UPDATE**:
Sorry, I'm so careless. The doc states it clearly. This method works according to the `value` passed to it, not the actual value of the named property stored in DB.
Source code on [Github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.java?source=cc):

```
public static Criterion eqOrIsNull(String propertyName, Object value) {
    return value == null
            ? isNull( propertyName )
            : eq( propertyName, value );
}
```

So in my case, `eqOrIsNull` returns `eq("")`. I should have used disjunction of `eq` and `isNull`, like Gregory [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325443/1125040).

Comment: For these kind of problems, you should enable debug logging. It will make hibernate print the executing sql.

Comment: It's sth like `select foo,bar from table where foo=? and bar=?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this code does what you want -

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("foo", ""), Restrictions.isNull("foo")))
                .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("bar", ""), Restrictions.isNull("bar")));
```

This snippet uses Hibernate 3.5.0-CR-2 API.

Comment: It works in this case, but if one column has non-empty content, it will also get that.

Comment: This one works...could you explain why is this different from `eqOrIsNull()` ? I'm using Hibernate 4.2.5.

Answer (score 4):

> Apply an "equal" constraint to the named property. If the value is
>   null, instead apply "is null".

This means, `is null` will be applied only if NULL is passed as the value.
If you specify any other string as value, only `equal` will be applied for that.

**This is useful when you're not sure about the actual value being passed at runtime as argument to the parameter value.** In such a scenario, in a traditional way, either you need to put a not null check & write criteria based on the not null condition or you need to write criteria in the way mentioned by Gregory's answer.

Keeping all these facts in mind, you should get answer of your question.
You're getting only those rows which contain empty value & not the one having NULL value, because you have specified an empty string as 2nd arguement. If you specify NULL as the 2nd arguement, you'll get only those rows having NULL value.

Let me know if that's helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have read the doc and source code and found my problem. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is very ambiguous if never used before and from a ORM abstraction perspective completely senseless to differentiate between eq null or is null. Thats legacy SQL thinking.

I first also thought it is a shortcut for `or(eq("foo"), isNull("foo"))`  cause i have my own filter layer on top on criteria where `eq` always works like `eqOrIsNull`.

**strong text**

```
/**
 * Checks if the given property is <code>null</code> or equals the given
 * value. If the given value is <code>null</code> it is only checked for
 * being <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param property Property name
 * @param value Value to check against
 *
 * @return Disjunction
 */
public static Criterion isValueEqOrNull(final String property, final Object value)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(property, "property must not be null");

    if (value == null)
        return Restrictions.isNull(property);
    else
        return Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq(property, value), Restrictions.isNull(property));
}
```